# Rapidly accessing collection through singleton vs direct reference

Tags: java

I have a collection that is defined in instance of singleton, the collection is accesed constantly (million of times).

Right now I am adding values to collection through the singleton:

```
DataRepository.getInstance().addToCollection(collectionId, value);
```

(In add collection method I first load the collection from hashmap by collectionId, and then add value to it)

Will I get any performance improvement if I load the instance of the collection and use the reference directly?

like:

```
CustomCollection collection =  DataRepository.getInstance().getCollection(collectionId);
```

Comment: you are making sure your implementation is thread safe, right?

Comment: You may or may not get a performance improvement. However, it's likely to be irrelevant in the broad context of the entire application. If you're concerned about performance, I would recommend that instead of guessing you use a profiler (such as YourKit) to find out where the time is spent.

Comment: @simpleuser: *"I first load the collection from hashmap by collectionId"*... If you're doing things millions of times with a HashMap, you'll probably gain **much** more by using hashmap implementations being way faster than the default HashMap.  For example you're talking about a *collectionID*: is this an integer (or can you make it an integer)?  If yes, then trash Java's default HashMap, install Colt or Trove, and use something like Trove's *TIntObjectHashMap*.  You'll be dodging millions and millions of pointless (un)wrapping from/to *int* to/from *Integer* and save memory as well...